# How do I integrate third-party payment gateways?

Tags: 8, webforms, payment-gateways

I need to integrate third-party payment gateways like Razorpay, Payu with Drupal 8 Webform.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a module available for Drupal 8.  [Payment for Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment_webform) existed for Drupal 7 but it is no longer being developed.

Instead, I would look at [Drupal Commerce](https://drupalcommerce.org/) if you need a full-featured solution to handle lots of options.

If your needs are more simple and you just need to embed a form and take payment, there are several non-Drupal solutions that you can integrate into Drupal the same as any other CMS (like Wordpress).

Comment: With Drupal Commerce, you can use the Commerce Webform Order module. (@see https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_webform_order)

Comment: Im not using commerce

Comment: @Vishak Then look for a third-party solution that lets you offload payment.  Webform doesn't support payment handling, and it would be an enormous project to add it (which is why Drupal Commerce exists).